# If works when serialprint bevor, without serial print if does not work

Tags: c++

this sketch works when "Serial.println(erstesObjekt.average());"  bevor "if (!Zykluspruefer)" but without the serial print the serial monitor does not show the value from the if. Here is my Code:

```
#include "DFRobot_MAX30102.h"
#include "filters.h"


DFRobot_MAX30102 particleSensor;

ZyklusSPO2 erstesObjekt; //Erzeugt ein erstes Objekt der Klasse ZyklusSPO2

bool Zykluspruefer;

void setup()
{
  //Init serial 
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!particleSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("MAX30102 was not found");
    delay(1000);
  }

  particleSensor.sensorConfiguration(/*ledBrightness=*/0x1F, /*sampleAverage=*/SAMPLEAVG_4, \
                                  /*ledMode=*/MODE_MULTILED, /*sampleRate=*/SAMPLERATE_400, \
                                  /*pulseWidth=*/PULSEWIDTH_411, /*adcRange=*/ADCRANGE_4096);

}


void loop()
{
  erstesObjekt.setSensorwert (particleSensor.getRed());

  //Serial.println("Im Zyklus");
  // Serial.println(erstesObjekt.getimzyklus ());
  Zykluspruefer = erstesObjekt.getimzyklus();
   //Serial.println(erstesObjekt.average());  

  if (!Zykluspruefer) 

  {
  Serial.println("Durchschnitt pro 10 Sekunden =");
  Serial.println(erstesObjekt.average());  
  Serial.println("AC = ");
  Serial.println(erstesObjekt.startecalculationAC());
  } 
}
```

Here is the class in the header:

```
 class ZyklusSPO2 { // Definition der Klasse ZyklusSPO2
  public: 
    const long interval = 10000; 
    float total_per_cycle = 0; 
    float AC = 0; 
    void setSensorwert(uint16_t Sensorwert);
    bool getimzyklus();
    int Sensorwertmaxtemp = 0; 
    int Sensorwertpeakpercylce = 0; 
    float startecalculationAC();
    unsigned long  previousMillis  = 0; 
    unsigned int cycle = 0; 
    float average() ;
    float average_per_cycle; 

    private:
    float Sensorwert;
    bool imzyklus = true;

}; 


#endif
```

Here is the function in the cpp:

```
oid ZyklusSPO2::setSensorwert(uint16_t sw){    
    Sensorwert = sw;
 }

bool ZyklusSPO2::getimzyklus()

 {

    return imzyklus; //Liefert den Bool Wert ob das Programm im Zyklus ist oder die Zeit abgelaufen ist 

 }


float ZyklusSPO2::average() {
   unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
   
   if (currentMillis - previousMillis <= interval)  {
        total_per_cycle = total_per_cycle + Sensorwert;
        cycle = cycle + 1; 
        imzyklus = true; 

        if (Sensorwert > Sensorwertmaxtemp)

        {
                  Sensorwertmaxtemp = Sensorwert;
        } 


   } else if (cycle > 0) {

        average_per_cycle = total_per_cycle/cycle;
        cycle = 0;
        total_per_cycle = 0;
        previousMillis = currentMillis; 
        Sensorwertmaxtemp = Sensorwertpeakpercylce; 
        imzyklus = false; 


    }

   return average_per_cycle; // liefert den letzten errechneten Wert zurück
   

}

float ZyklusSPO2::startecalculationAC() {

AC = (Sensorwertpeakpercylce - average_per_cycle)*2;
return AC;

}
```

I try also a while but the same problem. Without the serial print the serial monitor does not show the parameter i print in if, with serial monitor it works. Strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because calling `average()` in

```cpp
Serial.println(erstesObjekt.average());
```

sets `imzyklus = false`.

Then `Zykluspruefer = erstesObjekt.getimzyklus();` returns `false` and your condition, `if (!Zykluspruefer)`, will be `true` and the code int the following block will be executed.